# Transporting Failed While Publishing

Tags: 2013

While publishing, transporting is getting failed. When I checked the logs, I found below error.
"Unable to execute File retrieval on destination"

Please Help.

Thanks & Regards
Sharad Sangal

Comment: Can you explain where you found that error? Was that on the transport log or on the deployer log? Any more errors around that message? Are you using IIS or Java deployers? Unix or Windows?

Comment: I found it in the Transport Log. I am using IIS as .NET Application

Comment: @SharadSangal: Have a look at Julian's answer **[Publishing from a CMS to CDS of different CMS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11047437/500725)**. For me, it looks exactly the same issue you are facing.